# ¿Qué significa el neologismo "toñarse"? ¿De dónde viene?

Tags: verbos, significado, coloquialismos, españa, catalán

He visto en un par de ocasiones el verbo *toñarse*, que me parece que tiene un sonido muy divertido, en contextos como este:

> Me gustan [...] y los vídeos de cachorretes toñándose.

Por el contexto y otros ejemplos similares que he visto, me da la sensación de que significa lo mismo que "darse un golpe" o puede que "tropezar, caerse". Entiendo que se refiere a vídeos de cachorros dando sus primeros pasos y tropezando graciosamente.

La persona que escribió eso es catalana (o, al menos, vive allí), por lo que no sé si se puede tratar de un préstamo del catalán, aunque veo que existe la palabra *[toña](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a1roMoT)* con el significado regional de "pan grande" (en Aragón, registrado su uso con este significado desde 1855) e incluso "torta con aceite y miel" (en Murcia y Valencia, en el DLE desde 1925). Por tanto, igual que existe la expresión "darse una [torta](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a7yncrp)", en determinadas regiones puede haberse cambiado por "darse una toña" y de ahí "toñarse".

En todo caso:

- ¿Cuál es el significado del neologismo *toñarse*? ¿Cómo se usa actualmente?
- ¿De dónde viene la expresión?
- ¿En qué zonas de España se usa más?

Comment: *toña* también es borrachera, pensaba que *toñarse* era emborracharse

Comment: @blonfu creo que esa definición de [*toña*](http://www.furmientu.org/05Vocabularios2009/01Localismos.pdf) tiene una etimología distinta, i.e. que viene de una corrupción de [*moña*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=PlIDcFN) "6. f. coloq. Embriaguez, borrachera."

Answer (score 4):

Creo que es un calco del catalán [*tonyar*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=tonyar&Id=139891&search=tonyar) que tiene una signifiación similar de la que notas:

> **TONYAR** *v. tr.*
>
> 1. Fer tonys, abonyegar (Vall d'Àneu); cast. *abollar*.
> 2. Fènyer, donar a la pasta la forma que han de tenir els pans (Pallars, Tremp); cast. *heñir*. Quan la pasta ja és prou espessa... aleshores la tonyen, Violant Pa 78.
> 3. Cavar la terra profundament per a sembrar-la (Cullera, Gandia, Dénia, Pego, Sanet); cast. *cavar*.
>
>    Fon.: `toɲá` (occ.); `toɲáɾ` (val.).
>
>    Etim.: incerta. Potser derivat del cèltic tŭnna, ‘crosta, clovella’, com indica Corominas DECast, iv, 497. La relació amb [*tonya*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=tonya&Id=139887&search=tonya) art. 2 és evident, però no se sap si *tonyar* es deriva de *tonya* o si *tonya* és un postverbal de *tonyar*.

Además, el catalán [*tonya*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=tonya&Id=139887&search=tonya) es análago a [*torta*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a7yncrp) (i.e. ambos significan un tipo de pan o un golpe). Parece que las tres definiciones en el DLE de [*toña*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=a1roMoT) vienen directamente de las tres de *tonya*:

- un golpe → tala<sup>2</sup>.
- *Cat.* un tipo de pan<sup>1</sup> → rur. *Ar.* Pan grande, a veces de centeno.
- *Val.* un tipo de pan dulce → *Mur.* y *Val.* Torta amasada con aceite y miel.

---

<sup>1. Como un brioche no dulce.</sup>

Comment: Entiendo entonces que el uso de _tonyar_ en catalán haya fomentado la creación de _toñar_ en español. Sin embargo, veo que en 1985 la palabra _toña_ aparecía en el _Academia Manual_ de la RAE con los significados de "puñetazo" y "borrachera". También aparece como "golpe" en el _Diccionario de expresiones malsonantes_ (Martín, 1974) y como "bofetada, torta" en el _Diccionario manchego_ (Serna, 1974). Luego ya se usaba "dar una toña" antes de la aparición de este neologismo, al menos desde 1959 a juzgar por textos que he encontrado.

Comment: @charlie Ah, voy a aclarar: en catalá la palabra *tonya* significa pan igual que golpe, análago a 'torta' en castellano.